# jQuery - Continuously scroll div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I wish to build a shelf of content much like on Netflix where when you hover over arrows on either end the shelf scrolls at a continuous speed. Ideally, I would also like to make it so when you click the arrows it scrolls a chunk along, so you have the option to click like made to get through a shelf quickly.

This will be using lazy loading so you don't need to worry about repeating content, but obviously it won't have a set width (other then the outside container being 100% with overflow  scroll.

Also, this needs to be actually scrollable, so it will work on tablets/phones.

I have no idea here to start so any directions would be great.

Thanks,
Jake!

[Image of netflix shelf.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsGAw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Check out the [Smooth Div Scroll jQuery plugin](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com). It slides continuously through the image, you can hover the mouse on the div and manually scroll back- and forward.

**Original answer:**
I might be off with that, but check out these two plugins:

[jQuery Coverflow plugin](http://luwes.co/jquery-coverflow/) or the [jQuery Imageflow plugin](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/)

I think the keyword you are looking for is "flow" and there are multiple flow plugins for jQuery. Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Thanks for your help, but not quite what I'm after.. more of a continuous scrolling shelf than cover flow.

Comment: Okay, then check the "Smooth Div Scroll" jQuery plugin: http://smoothdivscroll.com/
It scrolls the images continuously :) I guess you can also add margins between the images so that you get the same view like in netflix.

Comment: You could also use the flex slider plugin which is pretty much customizable, e.g. for your case you could enable an auto-slideshow: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/